# loading Data fetched from the API after refreshing page in react using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am fetching array of objects from an API endpoint, 
I am using react-redux for state management.

I have two problems.

1. data gets fetched but only loads and displays after I refresh the page.
2. console logging single statement 4 times 2 blank array before setting state and 2 with data after setting state where it should have been only once I guess.

Following is my code.

Dashboard Action

```
import dashboardAPI from "../../../API/ShopUserAPI/dashboardAPI"

export const CURRENT_ORDER_LOAD = "CURRENT_ORDER_LOAD"
export const CURRENT_ORDER_FETCH = "CURRENT_ORDER_FETCH"
export const CURRENT_ORDER_ERROR = "CURRENT_ORDER_ERROR"

export const currentOrderAction = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({ type: CURRENT_ORDER_LOAD, payload: '' })
        dashboardAPI.get('/orders')
            .then(resp => {
                console.log(resp)
                dispatch({ type: CURRENT_ORDER_FETCH, payload: resp.data.data.orders })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
                dispatch({ type: CURRENT_ORDER_ERROR, payload: 'error occured. Retry !' })
            })
    }
}
```

Dashboard Reducer

```
import { CURRENT_ORDER_LOAD, CURRENT_ORDER_FETCH, CURRENT_ORDER_ERROR } from "../actions/dashboardActions";

const initialState = {
    isLoading: true,
    currentOrderData: [],
    currentOrdererror: ''
}

const dashboardReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CURRENT_ORDER_LOAD:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true
            }
        case CURRENT_ORDER_FETCH:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: false,
                currentOrderData: action.payload
            }
        case CURRENT_ORDER_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: false,
                currentOrdererror: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default dashboardReducer
```

Dashboard page

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Button, Typography, Grid, DialogContent, DialogActions, Dialog, DialogTitle, Divider, ExpansionPanel, ExpansionPanelSummary, ExpansionPanelDetails } from "@material-ui/core";
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import { connect } from "react-redux";


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  contentCenter: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: '1rem'
  },

  newSection: {
    marginTop: '1rem'
  },

  innerSection: {
    padding: '1rem'
  },

  heading: {
    fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(15),
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,

  },
  secondaryHeading: {
    fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(15),
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },

}))

const CurrentOrders = (props) => {

  console.log(props.currentOrderData) // console.log printing 4 times

  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);

  const handleChange = (panel) => (event, isExpanded) => {
    setExpanded(isExpanded ? panel : false);
  };

  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <div className={classes.newSection}>

      {/* current orders list */}
      <Typography className={classes.contentCenter}>
        Current orders
      </Typography>

      {/* Orders expansion panel list */}

      {props.currentOrderData.map(currentOrders => (
        <ExpansionPanel expanded={expanded === 'panel1'} onChange={handleChange('panel1')} className={classes.newSection}>
          <ExpansionPanelSummary
            expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
            aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
            id="panel1bh-header"
          >
            <Typography className={classes.heading}>Order ID: #{currentOrders.orderID}</Typography>
          </ExpansionPanelSummary>
          <ExpansionPanelDetails>
            <Grid container justify="space-between">
              <Grid item>
                <Link to="/order" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
                  <Button size="small" variant="contained" color="primary">
                    View Order
                </Button>
                </Link>
              </Grid>

            </Grid>
          </ExpansionPanelDetails>
        </ExpansionPanel>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    currentOrderData: state.dashboard.currentOrderData
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CurrentOrders)
```

I've dispatched dashboard action in the parent component of this page

DIspatching of Dashboard

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Container } from "@material-ui/core";
import CurrentOrders from "./CurrentOrders";
import TodaysOrders from "./TodaysOrders";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Button, Typography, Grid, DialogContent, DialogActions, Dialog, DialogTitle, Divider } from "@material-ui/core";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { currentOrderAction } from "../../../store/ShopUserStore/actions/dashboardActions";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  contentCenter: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: '1rem'
  },

  newSection: {
    marginTop: '1rem'
  },

  innerSection: {
    padding: '1rem'
  },

  buttonSuccess: {
    color: theme.palette.success.main
  }

}))

const Home = (props) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    props.getCurrentOrders()
  })

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        {/* shop status */}
        <Grid container justify="flex-start" className={classes.newSection}>
          <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen} className={classes.buttonSuccess}>
            Online
        </Button>
        </Grid>

        {/* shop status confirmation dialog */}
        <Dialog onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title" open={open}>
          <DialogTitle id="customized-dialog-title" onClose={handleClose}>
            Shop status
        </DialogTitle>
          <Divider />
          <DialogContent>
            <Typography className={classes.newSection}>
              Are you sure that you want to change shop status ?
          </Typography>
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button autoFocus onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
              No
          </Button>
            <Button autoFocus onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
              Yes
          </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>

        <Grid container spacing={3}
        >
          <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
            <CurrentOrders />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
            <TodaysOrders />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>

      </Container>

    </div>
  )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getCurrentOrders: () => dispatch(currentOrderAction())
  }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Home)
```

Comment: Can you show how/where are you dispatching `currentOrderAction`?

Comment: yes, just did in the question. @Maxali

Answer (score 0):

When you run your application, you should stumble into a nasty loop. The effect hook runs when the component mounts but also when the component updates. Because we are setting the state after every data fetch, the component updates and the effect runs again. It fetches the data again and again. That's a bug and needs to be avoided. We only want to fetch data when the component mounts. That's why you can provide an empty array as second argument to the effect hook to avoid activating it on component updates but only for the mounting of the component.

Try this:

```
useEffect(async () => {
    props.getCurrentOrders()
  }, []);
```

Comment: oh yeah iw as aware abt that mistakenly left out on adding it.
but still didnt resolved my question @taym95